# Pass Item as Derived Type from list of Base Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a two tier object hierarchy like so:

```
public class BaseStat
{
}

public class IndividualDefensiveStat: BaseStat
{
} //and many other stats that inherit from BaseStat
```

I then have a Generic Repository like so:

```
public class StatRepository<TDerived> where TDerived: BaseStat
{
    //ctr here

    public TDerived FindById(int? id)
    {
        if(!id.HasValue)
            throw new Exception("id has to have a value");

        var result = _context.Set<TDerived>().Find(id);

        return result;
    }

    public void Insert(TDerived item)
    {
        _context.Set<TDerived>().Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Finally I have a service class that accepts a data context, and does CRUD operations based on the derived type passed in:

```
public class StatDataService
{
    private IStatContext _context;

    public StatDataService(IStatContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void InsertData<TEntity>(TEntity item) where TEntity : BaseStat
    {
        var repo = getRepository<TEntity>();

        repo.Insert(item);
    }

    public TEntity GetById<TEntity>(int? id) where TEntity : BaseStat
    {
        return getRepository<TEntity>().FindById(id);
    }

    private StatRepository<TEntity> getRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity: BaseStat
    {
        return new StatRepository<TEntity>(_context);
    }

}
```

I would like to have a list of BaseStat that houses items that derive from it.  However, if I do a foreach loop and pass each item into the the Service's Insert method, TEntity/TDerived in this case is BaseStat.

How can I have TEntity/TDerived actually be the DerivedType that I am trying to target?

Comment: Generics are all resolved at compile-time. There's no dynamic dispatch.

Comment: So then what I want to do is not possible?

Comment: It's not possible to call a generic method with a type parameter that's not constant at compile time (without reflection). You may have to give up on your single `List<BaseStat>` and have one list per subclass. Or you could give up on generics, and switch to polymorphism..

Comment: or go this route:

statList.OfType<PassingStat>().ToList().ForEach(svc.InsertData);

            statList.OfType<RushingStat>().ToList().ForEach(svc.InsertData);

            statList.OfType<KickingStat>().ToList().ForEach(svc.InsertData);

            statList.OfType<IndividualDefensiveStat>().ToList().ForEach(svc.InsertData);

which isn't exactly elegant.